# What does subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having trouble visualizing what the subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ looks like. 
I've been taught it means a "space" which is a subset of the larger space $\mathbb R^n$, but then why is something like S = {[1, 1]} not a subspace in $\mathbb R^2$? It is just a subset of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: "what the subspace" there's your first problem. There are many subspaces.

Comment: Do you mean "linear subspace" maybe?

Comment: @umberto it wasn't a grammar point. I just wanted to clarify that there is not a single subspace which is a common misconception.

Answer (score 1):

A subspace is a subset which is a vector space in its own right.  That is, if you scale and add elements in the subspace, you get other elements in the subspace.  In particular, $ 0*(1,1) = (0,0) \not \in \{(1,1)\} $, so $ \{(1,1)\} $ is not a subspace of $ \mathbb{R}^{2} $.  The classic way to think of subspaces of $ \mathbb{R}^{n} $ is as lines, planes, and k-dimensional hyperplanes which pass through the origin in $ \mathbb{R}^{n} $.

Answer (score 0):

It's a subset $V$ of $\mathbb R^n$ that is a vector space. To avoid a classical mistake, notice that $\mathbb R^2$ is a vector space, but is not a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ when $n\geq 3$.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It is (or should be) obvious to say that vector spaces with more dimensions than the one in question are not a subset of that vector space.

Answer (score 0):

To say things easily, visualize Rⁿ as a space of n dimensions or n tuples. Thus to express mathematically, it is a space in which a point mass or a group of mass can have at most n parameters regarding it